# Is this the place to ask about measurements produced by spectrophotometer?

Tags: discussion

I have a question regarding some reflectance measurements produced from a spectrophotometer. This is to measure the coloration of bird plumage. Is Signal Processing an appropriate stack exchange site on which to ask this question?

Comment: I know quite a bit about spectrophotometers and color and I hang out almost exclusively at Signal Processing.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit too specific. We can always migrate it; let me think about where else on *.SE to ask.